# After I count the number of tables in a database, how do I actually use that value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

So I use this to find out how many tables there are...

```
<?php
    $db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'lists');
    $numoftables = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='lists'");
?>
```

but whenever I try to echo the value or use it in if statements it returns the value as "1" or sometimes "array" depending on how I do it, even though it says the value when I run the query in phpmyadmin. How do I echo the number of tables?

Comment: Could you echo the variable and show it here?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: This will work   <?php 
    $table_name = 'lists';
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'information_schema');
    $result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) total_rows FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '".$table_name."'");
    $table_rows = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo 'Total rows in '.$table_name.' = '.$table_rows['total_rows'];  
?>